# WordPress: When trying to save a menu item in /wp-admin/nav-menus.php a download appears

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing a weird problem. Unfortunately I don't find a solution online so I am asking the question here:

When I use WordPress and edit a menu I am trying to add, for example, a new menu item and hit "save menu".
Unfortunately, instead of saving, a download appears ("save as") that tries to save the current page (nav-menus.php) on my computer.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Is this a server problem?
I dont mind, if required, setting up the new menu item directly in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pure and simple, this only happen when your web server doesn't recognize the file format as executable and hence it offers to download it (happens with zipped files for example) or there are HTTP headers set to force the download which could happen from improper code or installed plugins

Answer (score 1):

Hum, that's a weird problem.  Something is registered to the menu save (which is an `update` action) and is causing the behavior.

Now we put on our troubleshooting hat and systematically walk through to discover the root cause.  Once you find it, then you can craft a plan to fix the problem.

Let me ask you:  Are you able to edit/create and save Posts, Pages, and widgets?  If no, then contact your web host provider to ensure everything is cool on their end.  Otherwise, continue on.

### Gathering Clues

Let's note what you see as these are clues.

- Does it happen on one specific menu?  Or all of them?
- When you click, "Save Menu" look at the URL in your browser's address field.  What does it say when you get the download UI?  It should be: `yourdomain.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`.
- If you hit "cancel" for the download UI, what happens?

  - Did it save the menu? Refresh the screen and see it the menu saved.

### Eliminating Variables

Let's eliminate as many variables as we can by:

1. Deactivate ALL plugins
2. Switch theme to one of the WordPress default themes.
3. Now try it again.

#### Does the problem disappear?

Yes, it's gone. Okay, now you know one of the plugins or your theme is causing the behavior.  Now you want to reactive them one-by-one to find which one is doing it.

#### Nope, the problem remains?

Okay, it's not the plugins or themes.  That's good to know.  What could be then?

It's either :

- Something touched one or more of the WordPress Core files
- Or something in the database

At this point, I'd reload WordPress Core to eliminate it.  Delete everything except:

- `wp-config.php`
- `wp-content` folder (that's all of your plugins, theme, and uploads

Repeat.  Did it go away?  If no, look at the `wp-config.php` file.  Make sure there's nothing weird in there that might have been added. Otherwise, post here again and we can all chat about it.

Answer (score 0):

I very rarely have the same problem (depends on the server), and found a workaround:

The problem (at least in my case) only appeared, when I tried to save menu items that are custom URLs. For example, a Link to a YouTube Channel, like `https://youtube.com/channel/123456` would fail, but saving `https:/youtube.com` would succeed.

The workaround is to escape all slashes in the url (except https://), like this:
`https://youtube.com\/channel\/123456`
after saving, the correct URL will appear and it will work correctly in the front-end.
When you need to re-save the menu, you need to re-escape all the slashes again.

I do not know what causes this behaviour, but maybe this workaround helps other people, or myself in the future.